# Automatic creation of python conda packages

Tags: python, bash, installer

I packaged a pure python library using conda. 
It is tested to work with 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6 and should work on all three mayor operating systems.

I am quite surprised, that there is no command or option like `conda-build-all`. Instead I have to build and convert manually.

So there are two questions:

Is the idea to just put the tasks into a shell script sane? It feels wrong.

Is the shell script written in a maintaineable manner?

```
#!/bin/sh

# ====================================================
# Please note the bug, that for conda-build the option '--output' does
# not respect the directories given by '--output-folder':
# https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/1957
# ====================================================

tmp=$(dirname $(conda-build --output .))
system=$(basename $tmp)
root_dir=$(dirname $tmp)


for py_version in '2.7' '3.5' '3.6'
do
  package_name=$(basename $(conda-build --python ${py_version} --output .))
  package_path="${root_dir}/${py_version}/${system}/${package_name}"

  conda-build --no-anaconda-upload \
              --python ${py_version} \
              --output-folder "${root_dir}/${py_version}" .
  for platform in 'osx-64' 'linux-32' 'linux-64' 'win-32' 'win-64'
  do
    conda-convert -p ${platform} -o "${root_dir}/${py_version}" ${package_path}
    anaconda upload "${root_dir}/${py_version}/${platform}/${package_name}"
  done
done
```

PS: Here you can find the [module](https://github.com/mcocdawc/chemcoord/tree/ae781f3360691cc1d4a654d5cb4f9dc0694dd7d3/) and the [shell script](https://github.com/mcocdawc/chemcoord/blob/ae781f3360691cc1d4a654d5cb4f9dc0694dd7d3/conda.recipe/build_conda_packages.sh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quoting

It's recommended to quote variables in command arguments that might contain spaces, for example here:

```
tmp=$(dirname "$(conda-build --output .)")
system=$(basename "$tmp")
root_dir=$(dirname "$tmp")
```

The version numbers here don't contain characters that the shell would interpret, so you could drop all the single quotes. But you don't have to.

> ```
> for py_version in '2.7' '3.5' '3.6'
> ```

Here again:

> ```
> package_name=$(basename $(conda-build --python ${py_version} --output .))
> ```

It would be better to quote the command arguments:

```
package_name=$(basename "$(conda-build --python ${py_version} --output .)")
```

I wouldn't double-quote `${py_version}` though,
because we have established earlier that it cannot possibly contain special characters.

This is fine:

> ```
> package_path="${root_dir}/${py_version}/${system}/${package_name}"
> ```

But you could write simpler as:

```
package_path=$root_dir/$py_version/$system/$package_name
```

That is, the double-quoting is not necessary in variable assignments,
only in command line arguments.

This is fine:

> ```
> for platform in 'osx-64' 'linux-32' 'linux-64' 'win-32' 'win-64'
> ```

But you could write more concisely as:

```
for platform in osx-64 linux-{32,64} win-{32,64}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I will pay more attention when to quote my commands